# Netty - Boss thread implementation

Tags: multithreading, netty

I was wondering how is the boss thread and listening implemented inside Netty? Is it busy waiting like in a while loop? Does it burn any CPU cycles when there are no new connections or is it event-based that gets woken up when needed?

Comment: As far as I know boss thread sleeps on the selector for server socket most of the time. After accepting connection that connection is registered with a worker. From that moment on worker is responsible for serving that connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses Selector.select() which blocks until there is a socket to accept. So no it not burns any CPU but waits on the OS the get notified as soon as there is some work to do.